# Android Studio Emulator - I don't have Intel Visualisation Technology

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, intel, windows-7-x64

I have checked and I am almost certain my laptop Sony Vaio does not support the Intel Visualisation Technology (I have Intel Core Duo T6600). Does this mean there is no way for me to run the emulator on my laptop?
Are there any work arounds?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can still use the default ARM system images in the SDK manager (Edit: You can also use the Intel Atom system images, but just without HAXM turned on, so expect some sluggishness and jitter.)

[image: ARM system image in the SDK Manager]

After downloading them, either create and launch  the virtual images by accessing Manage AVD menu in the SDK Manager (feel free to use the presets):

[image: Manager Window]

or using Android Studio AVD manager (which is much better imho):

[image]